# Symfony2 Saving data of related Entity after submiting form

Tags: php, symfony, orm, entity, relation

I'm starting developing with Symfony2 and looks like I need help. I have Product entity related with SynchronizationSetting entity. I can edit product data by form maped with his entity. But I also need to modify some data related to product in SynchronizationSetting. To do that I've modified the form so it look like that (Vendor\ProductBundle\Form\ProductType.php):

```
...
    ->add('synchronization_setting', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('daily' => 'Daily', 'weekly' => 'Weekly', 'never' => 'Never'))
```

After form is submitted selected checkbox values are passed to setSynchronizationSetting method in Product Entity. Then I do that (Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\SynchronizationSetting.php):

```
public function setSynchronizationSetting($data)
{
        $synchronizationSetting = new SynchronizationSetting();
        $synchronizationSetting->setDaily(in_array('daily', $data) ? '1' : '0');
...
}
```

And now I need to somehow save those SynchronizationSetting entity into database. I read that calling entity manager from here is very bad practice so... how should I save this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way (I'm not sure if it's good practice)

```
public function setSynchronizationSetting($data)
{
         $synchronizationSetting = new SynchronizationSetting();
         $synchronizationSetting->setDaily(in_array('daily', $data) ? '1' : '0');
}

public function retSynchronizationSetting()
{
    return $this->synchronizationSetting;
}
```

Then in your controller in place where you handle form data you call retSynchronizationSetting() and save entity using EntityManager.